# Add an ID to a <ul> when it has a specific class - onclick jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a unordered list which has a class of .gallery.

I have a button which when clicked i want to add an ID #sortable to that ul targeting the the ul with the class .gallery?

when the button is clicked again i need it to toggle the id adding and removing it?

```
 <a href="#" class="clickMetoAddSortable">Click to add ID to ul</a>

    <ul id="id of sortable to go here when clicked" class="gallery">
        <li>one</li>
        <li>two</li>
        <li>three</li>
    </ul>
```

How can i do this in jQuery?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Unless you can absolutely guarantee there will only be a single element with the class `gallery` on it, this isn't a good idea.

Comment: why not toggle a class of the UL instead of changing ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On click of your button -

```
$('ul.gallery').prop('id','sortable');
```

To toggle id -

```
  if($('#sortable').length){
    $('ul.gallery').prop('id','');
  }else{
    $('ul.gallery').prop('id','sortable'); 
  }
```

Comment: can it be toggled adding and removing the id when clicking on the button?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this should work

```
$("button").on("click", function() {
   $('ul.gallery').prop('id','sortable');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $("your button id").click(function(){
    $('ul.gallery').prop('id','sortable');
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
if($('ul.gallery').prop('id')=='sortable')
    $('ul.gallery').prop('id','');
else
   $('ul.gallery').prop('id','sortable');
```

Comment: You should not use attr() for this purpose any more. While this might have worked in the past, the latest versions of jQuery now strictly separate the behaviors of attributes from properties.

Comment: @Steve that's true even ID is an attribute and in fact it is not a good idea to modificate an ID attribute 'on the fly'. I cannot think any good reason of doing that. {the last part of comment is more for OP}

Answer (score 0):

```
$("button").on("click",function(){

      $("ul.gallery").prop('id','sortable');
});
```

Modify selectors according your DOM in case any mismatch.